# Ehcache Mbean not visible in Hawtio GUI

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache, jmx, mbeans, hawtio

I have configured Ehcache with my Spring Boot project and JPA/Hibernate. I know, that I can try to monitor Ehcache via JMX. Ehcache is definitly working right now.  I have also installed Hawtio GUI and can successfully monitor Embedded ActiveMQ but I'm unable to find Ehcache Mbean there.

How to activate Ehcache Mbean in order to be able to view it in Hawtio GUI?

Comment: Can you find ehcache mbeans using jconsole?  If not, it's likely that the jmx feature for ehcache is just turned off.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I also can't find ehcache mbeans using jconsole. How to enable ehcache mbeans in Spring Boot ?

Comment: You may find this helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520778/enabling-jmx-support-in-ehcache-3-1-2